# Compare columns of numpy matrix with array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy matrix and want to compare every columns to a given array, like:

```
M = np.array([1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,2]).reshape((3,3)).T
v = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Now I want to compare every columns of M with v, i.e. I want a matrix with the first column consisting of True, True, True. A second saying False, True, False. A third True, False, False.

How do I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use broadcasted comparison:

```
>>> M == v[:, None]
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

Comment: No, now it is OK

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `np.equal` column-wise:

```
np.array([np.equal(col, v) for col in M.T]).T
```

it compares the elements of two numpy arrays element-wise. The `M.T` makes for loop to pop your original `M` columns as one-dimensional arrays and the final transpose is needed to reverse it.
[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html) the equal/not_equal functions are described.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could match each row in the matrix with the given vector using [np.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
>>> M
array([[1, 3, 1],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2]])
>>> v
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x==v, 1, M)
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```